# How to hide header in mui mobile datepicke?

Tags: material-ui, datepicker

how to hide this block on mobile version mui datepicker?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You must set the `showToolbar`prop to `false` in order to hide that section. The documentation says that `false` is the default value, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
 <MobileDatePicker
    ...
    showToolbar={false}
 />
```